# Windows Server 2012R2: Why does process survive "successful" taskkill?

Tags: windows, windows-service

I have a problem where IIS fails to shut down properly. IOW, when we do the standard NET STOP / NET START sequence, we end up with a service that is shutting down...forever. This causes my application deployment to fail when it tries to restart IIS.

I thought I would migrate to using taskkill. But the results below mystify me. taskkill reports successful termination, but the process is still there.

How do I make taskkill do what is needed?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>tasklist /svc|find "W3SVC"
svchost.exe                   1456 W3SVC, WAS

C:\Users\Administrator>taskkill /PID 1456 /F
SUCCESS: The process with PID 1456 has been terminated.

C:\Users\Administrator>tasklist /svc|find "W3SVC"
svchost.exe                   1456 W3SVC, WAS

C:\Users\Administrator>taskkill /PID 1456 /F
ERROR: The process with PID 1456 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.

C:\Users\Administrator>tasklist /svc|find "W3SVC"
svchost.exe                   1456 W3SVC, WAS

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Comment: Does the GUI report that it's still running?

Comment: What PID is returned if you find for "WAS" ?

Comment: do you get the same result if you stop the service first? In powershell: `Get-Service W3SVC | Stop-Service; Get-Process W3SVC | Stop-Process`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause of your problem is a known issue in the July security update, [KB4338815](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4338815/windows-81-update-kb4338815):

> When an administrator tries to stop the World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC), the W3SVC remains in a "stopping" state, but cannot fully stop or be restarted.

The resolution is to install either [KB4345424](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4345424/improvements-and-fixes-windows-8-1-and-server-2012-r2), [KB4338831](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4338831/july172018kb4338831osbuildpreviewofmonthlyrollup), or any later cumulative update.